# Считывает "новые" данные быстрее чем их же записывает

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Суть проблемы: Функция (х) отправляет запрос в php файл, там он обрабатывается и происходит UPDATE в sql. После отправки запроса вызывается функция (у) которая обновляет состояние непосредственно в html, она делает запрос в базу и смотрит что там.Так вот, при вызове (х) данные на странице остаются предыдущими,то есть если мы..

пишем в базу: 1 отображается 0

пишем в базу: 2 отображается 1

и так далее, думаю суть ясна. Я засовываю функцию (у) в timeOut, но он не спасает что то, что можно в данной ситуации предпринять?

```
 function dbWrite(id, name)
{
    var que = 'UPDATE test SET name = ' + name + ' WHERE id = ' + id;
    $.post(
           'connect.php', 
           {query: que}, 
           function(answer)
           {
           });
    setTimeout(test1(id), 1000);
}

function test1 (id)
{
$.post(
       'connect.php', 
       {id: id,}, 
       function(workJson)
       {
           alert(workJson);
       });
}
```

Comment: Что то странное, можно решить как будто у вас функции работают в разных коннектах к базе и при этом после update не был дан commit

Comment: Код на стороне js покажите

Comment: код приложил, может нельзя так делать?

Comment: Во-первых вы зря пишите запрос sql на клиентской стороне. Взлом гарантирован. А во-вторых. Почему на серверной стороне нельзя записать и вернуть выборку одновременно?

Comment: потому что я новичек и много не знаю)

Comment: `setTimeout(test1(id), 1000);` - неправильно - `test1` вызывается, а не подается в `setTimeout`. `setTimeout(function() { test1(id); }, 1000);` - правильнее, но тоже плохо. `function(answer) { test1(id); }` - правильно.

Comment: спасибо! что то я даже не подумал о том что она вызывается, хоть это и было очевидно

Comment: 100% согласен с тем что запросы нельзя писать в js, принимая запрос из js вы даете полный доступ к своей базе.

Answer (score 3):

Не нужен никакой timeOut, посылаете ajax запрос в асинхронном режиме на обновление, дожидаетесь ответа потом обновляете данные на странице:

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/ajax.php",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data)
   {
      // здесь обновляем данные на странице
   }
 });
```

И все это надо делать в одной функции а не в двух разных. И кстати два запроса это не очень красиво, если первый запрос вернулся без ошибок, просто обновите dom дерево без второго запроса, теми данными которые вы посылали на сервер для обновления. Два запроса это лишняя нагрузка.